# Find the solution for differential equation $x^2(dy/dx) + 2xy = y^3$

Tags: differential

I tried solving this by bernoulli type , but coefficient didn't came appropriate.

Comment: Maybe try for a solution of the form $y=\lambda x^n$?

Comment: Divide both sides by $x^2$, and you'll find that this is indeed a [Bernoulli differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_differential_equation)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom i found $dv/dx -1/x = y^2/(-2(x^2))$ where $v=y^(1-n) = y^(-2)$ but can't go any further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide by $y^2$ to get $\frac{x^2}{y^3}\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{2x}{y^2}=1$.

Substitute $\frac{1}{y^2}=z$ which gives $\frac{1}{y^3}\frac{dy}{dx} =\frac{-1}{2}\frac{dz}{dx}$ to get Linear differential equation

$\frac{dz}{dx}-\frac{4}{x}z=\frac{-2}{x^2}$ which you can solve.